# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes and hangs

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on dual boot with Windows 10, and since yesterday I have been experiencing strange in my laptop: symptoms are basically the ones pointed out in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=227959) post.

It sometimes freezes and it acts like I'm keeping pressing some letters of my keyboard. If I try to shut it down, it hangs and won't shut down, even if forcing it by keeping pressed the button power for long time. Unfortunately battery is unremovable, so when it happens I need to let the battery die out, or else the laptop is unusable.

However trying to shut it down lately, I think it has entered power safe mode, therefore battery will run out in a large time (hopefully not days, but who knows...). Only then I'll be able to tell what kernel it has.

My laptop is a clevo Intel i7-10870H with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Ti. Model was bought from pcspecialist, and it is Cosmos IX.

Nevertheless I was able to access kernel logs and it keeps flooding the following messages (see last rows):

```
Mar 24 14:10:56 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [17475.860100] nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Correcting number of heads for current head configuration (0x00)
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.116735] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered blocking state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.116737] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered disabled state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.116790] device vethb616131 entered promiscuous mode
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.116880] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered blocking state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.116881] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered forwarding state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.117136] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered disabled state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.315577] eth0: renamed from vethb93e106
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.343587] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethb616131: link becomes ready
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.343632] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered blocking state
Mar 24 14:51:35 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19915.343633] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered forwarding state
Mar 24 14:52:55 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19995.400445] vethb93e106: renamed from eth0
Mar 24 14:52:55 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19995.480033] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered disabled state
Mar 24 14:52:55 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19995.486402] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered disabled state
Mar 24 14:52:55 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19995.488188] device vethb616131 left promiscuous mode
Mar 24 14:52:55 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [19995.488192] docker0: port 2(vethb616131) entered disabled state
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093638] ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20190816/evregion-266)
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093644] ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20190816/evregion-275)
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093656] 
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093656] Initialized Local Variables for Method [ZEVT]:
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093656]   Local0: 00000000cb9845a1 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093660] Initialized Arguments for Method [ZEVT]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093661]   Arg0:   00000000feee066f <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093662]   Arg1:   00000000a22cc24e <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000064
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093664]   Arg2:   00000000f5b523e8 <Obj>           Package 00000000f5b523e8
Mar 24 14:58:31 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20331.093668] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.DCHU.ZEVT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20190816/psparse-531)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593645] ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20190816/evregion-266)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593650] ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20190816/evregion-275)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593660] 
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593660] Initialized Local Variables for Method [ZEVT]:
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593661]   Local0: 000000007d9d9a5a <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593664] Initialized Arguments for Method [ZEVT]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593665]   Arg0:   0000000082af1a3e <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593667]   Arg1:   00000000064a763a <Obj>           Integer 000000000000006E
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593668]   Arg2:   00000000c32aa766 <Obj>           Package 00000000c32aa766
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593673] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.DCHU.ZEVT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20190816/psparse-531)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593697] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.DCHU._DSM due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20190816/psparse-531)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593705] ACPI: \_SB_.DCHU: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x11)
Mar 24 14:58:33 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20333.593706] clevo_acpi: failed to evaluate _DSM
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093720] ACPI Error: AE_TIME, Returned by Handler for [EmbeddedControl] (20190816/evregion-266)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093725] ACPI Error: Timeout from EC hardware or EC device driver (20190816/evregion-275)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093736] 
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093736] Initialized Local Variables for Method [ZEVT]:
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093737]   Local0: 00000000f8ae56ff <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093740] Initialized Arguments for Method [ZEVT]:  (3 arguments defined for method invocation)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093740]   Arg0:   00000000dcbb3f8d <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093742]   Arg1:   000000003b4aeb04 <Obj>           Integer 000000000000006E
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093744]   Arg2:   000000003aa2325b <Obj>           Package 000000003aa2325b
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093748] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.DCHU.ZEVT due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20190816/psparse-531)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093773] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.DCHU._DSM due to previous error (AE_TIME) (20190816/psparse-531)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093780] ACPI: \_SB_.DCHU: failed to evaluate _DSM (0x11)
Mar 24 14:58:36 andrea-NP50DE-DB kernel: [20336.093781] clevo_acpi: failed to evaluate _DSM
```

Any suggestions to fix the problem? I saw somewhere that maybe upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04LTS might fix it... Moreover I found it can be something hardware related (maybe GPU), but honestly idk, since it's never show any problem up to now and I have not installed anything recently (maybe I did upgrade the kernel yesterday, I saw a new version has been released lately so I night have done it...). But still don't know whether all this can be related

(Sorry for my multiple edits, but formatting via phone is kinda hard and many thanks for your patience)

Comment: Hello @Andrea  , I also have a similar problem. I'm on ubuntu 20.04.2, my computer is a Tuxedo (clevo based) I also have a Intel Core i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 16 with a NVIDIA  GeForce RTX 3070. the first time it happened to me, the computer was getting very hot and closing the lid didn't made it to sleep so I had to wait until my battery died and now the battery is always at 0% and if I unplug the charger, it immediately turns off :(
Did you succeed in solving the issue? because it still happens to me very randomly, without a specific pattern...

Comment: I can see that it happens right after something is happenning with the network and it's also happenning after ssl related things for me too. It might be the source?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I cannot help you. At the end, I gave up and installed only Windows (using WSL for my stuff). Using only Windows I have not face any problem related to it. 
However,  I do not know whether is related to SSL/Networking or any other topic, since I was not even even to understand from where the problem was arising. Maybe processor is involved too since it is common to both us, but unluckily I was not helped and myself am not able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue so I'll post what I've found so far, maybe it'll helps others that are dealing with the same.

There seems to be an issue with some clevo/tuxedo keyboard drivers, I'm having the same behavior and logs on my kubuntu focus (as it uses tuxedo keyboards) with Kubuntu 22.04.

On this reddit thread on r/tuxedocomputers the answer to this same issue was to do a bios/ec update https://www.reddit.com/r/tuxedocomputers/comments/vwqm70/embedded_control_error_and_unable_to_power_off/

I'm asking help to KFocus support team on this as well, will edit this answer if I get confirmation if that update solves the issue.

EDIT:

After the bios/ec update the issue was gone. Consider reaching to tech support of your laptop to get the update